# Is it Safe to Install SQL Server 2012 on a machine which have SQL Server 2008 R2 running?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 quite a while. It is working great. Now I need to use SQL Server 2012. Will this effect my existing database. How much Risk involved in installing SQL Server 2012 on a machine that have SQL Server 2008 R2 running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Back the whole system and the databases up and follow the upgrade instructions and you'll be fine.

Comment: Silly question. How to back-up whole system?

Comment: Yes, that is a silly question as you should alreay be doing backups of your systems. Quickest easiest way to take a single backup is using the Windows Backup Componets; you will need to add that feature to your windows install.

Comment: @MarkHenderson, Is Windows Backup Componets is available in Windows 7? Sorry I am beginner?

Comment: Oh for heavens sake, are you doing this on Windows 7? if so then please read our FAQ, this site is for PROFESSIONAL sysadmins, who would never do this.

Comment: @user960567 Windows 7 is *NOT* a supported OS for SQL Server

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 Professional is supported for Standard, Home basic is supported for express, but chances are you're not going to have the horses behind it to do anything useful

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of-course it is safe. There are two possible ways :

1. Upgrade your existing instance : In this case I would suggest you download and follow Upgrade Advisor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256.aspx
2. Installing named instance : Another option is to install a named instance, this way you will have both the instances available - SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012.